# K alpha and K beta, which one has more energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation, x-rays

I have a question regarding K-alpha and K-beta in X-rays. I examined the intensity vs. wavelength diagram and concluded that K-beta has more energy than K-alpha but K-beta is more intense. Am I correct? if so, is that always the case?

Comment: Did you mean *but K-**alpha** is more intense*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $K_\alpha$ is produced by the $2p \to 1s$ transition and the $K_\beta$ is produced by the $3p \to 1s$ transition. So the $K_\beta$ radiation has a higher energy than the $K_\alpha$ transition.

If you look at a typical spectrum:

[image: X-ray spectrum]

(picture from [the Arizona State University web site](https://www.asu.edu/courses/phs208/patternsbb/PiN/act/electrons/electrons.shtml))

then you can see the $K_\alpha$ has a longer wavelength than the $K_\beta$, and a longer wavelength means a lower energy since the energy is given by:

$$ E = h\nu = \frac{hc}{\lambda} $$

The $K_\alpha$ normally has the higher intensity since the probability that the X-rays will cause a $n=1 \to N$ transition generally falls with increasing $N$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have another question. Why there are no K-alpha and K-beta lines in W (tungsten)  x-ray diagram?

Comment: @Yushi the tungsten $K_\alpha$ and $K_\beta$ lines are at 60keV and 70keV respectively. Many X-rays tubes operate at energies lower than this so they cannot excite the tungsten $n=1 \to 2$ and $n=1 \to 3$ transitions. If you operate the X-ray tube at a high enough energy you will see these lines.